# Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings in Netbeans?

Tags: slf4j, netbeans-8

There seems to be an interesting issue with classpaths when running code in NetBeans.  I'm getting the multiple binding error there (but not outside NetBeans).  The relevant information is:

```
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/C:/Users/bknoblauch/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Door/src/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [file:/C:/Users/bknoblauch/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Door/build/classes/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

...where it appears to be finding both the source AND the compiled versions.  I suspect it has something to do with project run-time libraries including both "Classpath for Compiling Sources" as well as "Compiled Sources".  I can't even (just for testing) remove either of those from the run system.  Any other ideas?